# Mapping ForAllTheRestOfMembers

Tags: c#, automapper

I was thinking if there's something similar to that, i.e. map an object in whatever way and use a custom resolution for all the rest of the properties that are not mapped yet. Would look similar to this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<source, destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop1, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Property1)) // for example
    .ForAllTheRestOfMembers(opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());
```

I'm pretty sure there's no such thing in Automapper, so I was thinking if there was another library with such a feature or if would it be feasible to some how extend Automapper and create such a method

Thanks